# Fetch value from one child element and display it as output of another child element using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I have the following xml snippet:

```
<Data>
<Entry>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Plan>DC</Plan>
    <Effective_Date>02/12/2021</Effective_Date>
    <tax>Employer Extra care</tax>
    <Value>28.85</Value>
</Entry>
<Entry>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Plan>HC</Plan>
    <Effective_Date>02/12/2021</Effective_Date>
    <tax>HC care</tax>
    <Value>105.77</Value>
</Entry>
<Entry>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Plan>DC</Plan>
    <Effective_Date>02/12/2021</Effective_Date>
    <tax>Employee Extra Care </tax>
    <Value>115.38</Value>
</Entry>
<Entry>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <Plan>DC</Plan>
    <Effective_Date>02/10/2021</Effective_Date>
    <tax>Employer Extra care</tax>
    <Value>30</Value>
</Entry>
    <Entry>
        <ID>2</ID>
        <Plan>DC</Plan>
        <Effective_Date>02/10/2021</Effective_Date>
        <tax>Employee Extra care</tax>
        <Value>100</Value>
    </Entry>
</Data>
```

The output that I'd want would be :

```
 ID | Plan | Employee_Value | Employer_Value | Effective_Date
  1 | DC    | 115.38         | 28.85          | 02/12/2021
  1 | HC    | 105.77         |                | 02/12/2021
  2 | DC    |  100           | 30             | 02/10/2021
```

Explaining the output, if a particular ID has two plans, DC and HC, it should be in two different rows. For the 'DC' row, the `Employee_Value` column should have `Value` from the `Entry` tag where `tax` element value is `Employee extra care` and `Employer_Value` column should have `value` from the `Entry` tag where `tax` element value is `Employer extra care`. As for the 'HC' row, the `Employee_Value` column should have `Value` from the `Entry` tag where `tax` element value is `HC care`and `Employer_Value` column is blank. Also, `Effective_Date` value can be from either of the `Entry` tags that have `Plan` as 'DC' as `Effective_Date` value remains same for both.

I tried looping through each `Entry` and saving the `Value` in a variable when `tax` element is `Employer extra care` but the variable is out of scope when it iterates over other `entry` tags.

Let me know if you need further info !!

Answer (score 0):

Here's something to help you get started :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        version="2.0">
    
        <xsl:output method="text"/>
        
        <xsl:key name="entryKey" match="Entry" use="ID"/>
    
        <xsl:template match="/">
            <xsl:text> ID | Plan | Employee_Value | Employer_Value | Effective_Date</xsl:text><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="Data/Entry" group-by="concat(ID,Plan)">
                <xsl:value-of select="current-group()[1]/ID"/><xsl:text> | </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="current-group()[1]/Plan"/><xsl:text> | </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="if(current-group()[1]/Plan='DC')
                                        then key('entryKey',current-group()[1]/ID)[tax='Employee Extra Care']/Value 
                                        else ''"/><xsl:text> | </xsl:text>
                <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:template>
      
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You can use the same kind of instructions to implement the rest of your requirements.

See it working here : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/aiyneN